# useSelector hook : how to use the second argument correctly (shallowEqual)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have this code snipet that i grap the count from the store..

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider, useSelector, useDispatch, shallowEqual } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";

function count(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
   }
}

const store = createStore(count);

function App() {
  const count = useSelector(state => state, shallowEqual);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
}
```

which is the difference if i will use the shallowEqual in useSelector in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are returning primitive value from selector so it won't make a difference if you use shallowCopy or not,
by default it compares through strict === reference equality check

you can use `shallowEquals` when you select an object that might be similar in contents but different by reference.

for e.g

```
const a = { key1 : "hello" }
const b = { key1 : "hello" }

console.log( a === b ) // will log false
console.log( shallowEquals(a, b)) // will log true
```

so if you return object from your useSelector method and you want to compare only contents then you can use shallowCopy to avoid extra rerenders

e.g

```
useSelector(state => ({count : state }), shallowEqual);
```

useSelector will compare the content of object, if they are same it won't rerender